# Symfony2 / PUGXMultiUserBundle : I can register only one type of user

Tags: symfony

I installed PUGXMultiUserBundle. If I go to /register/member or /register/repairer and submit the registration, it's always a new member that is added in my database. I don't understand why. But, when i switch the users in config.yml (repairer in first and member in second), it's repairer that is added in database.

config.yml

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: Test\UserBundle\Entity\User
service:
    user_manager: pugx_user_manager

pugx_multi_user:
users:
user_member:
    entity:
      class: Test\UserBundle\Entity\Member
    registration:
      form:
        type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        name: fos_user_registration_form
        validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
      template: FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig
    profile:
      form:
        type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
        name: fos_user_profile_form
        validation_groups:  [Profile, Default]
user_repairer:
    entity:
      class: Test\UserBundle\Entity\Repairer
    registration:
      form:
        type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
      template: FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig
    profile:
      form:
        type: FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
```

routing.yml

```
member_registration:
pattern:  /register/member
defaults: { _controller: TestUserBundle:RegistrationMember:register }

repairer_registration:
pattern:  /register/repairer
defaults: { _controller: TestUserBundle:RegistrationRepairer:register }
```

Controller1

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller as BaseController;

class RegistrationMemberController extends BaseController
{
public function registerAction()
{
    return $this->container
                ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
                ->register('Test\UserBundle\Entity\Member');
}
}
```

Controller2

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller as BaseController;

class RegistrationRepairerController extends BaseController
{
public function registerAction()
{
    return $this->container
                ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
                ->register('Test\UserBundle\Entity\Repairer');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this resolution https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/issues/29

hope it will help you